# I am stuck with time complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I am studying the time complexity of algorithms and I am stuck with something. Can you help me find the time complexity of the below code? Thanks.

```cpp
x=1;
for(i=0; i<=n-1; i++){
        for(int j=1; j<=x; j++)
            std::cout<<j<< std::endl;
        x =x*2;
    }
```

Comment: What do you think the time complexity is? Why?

Comment: Time complexity is O(2^n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a walkthrough of my thinking process:

1. The first for-loop runs `n` times, so time complexity is **O(n)**.
2. The second for-loop increases by twice in the number of loops as the first for-loop moves on, so time complexity is **O(2^n)**.
3. Combining the two, it looks like the code has time complexity of **O(n*2^n)**.
4. However, you think more deeply, this is incorrect.
5. If you consider number of loops that the second for-loop runs, it is 1, 2, 4, 8, ... , 2^(n-2), 2^(n-1).
6. Thus, the total number of loops would be 2^(n-1) + 2^(n-2) + ... + 2^1 + 2^0.
7. For any given x, x + x/2 + x/4 + ... + 2 + 1 = 2*x - k (where value of k depends).
8. Applying the same concept, the total number of loops is 2*2^(n-1).
9. As a result, the overall time complexity is **O(2^n)**.